# FadeToggle Expands Entire List

Tags: css, list, toggle, expand

When I toggle my drop down menu, the entire list expands. Ive been trying to figure out how to expand the selected list only but don't know where the issue is.

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cx4CK/6/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><h1>Applications</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><h1>Forum</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><h1>Guilds</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><h1>Imageboards</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><h1>Projects</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation ul li h1 {
    background : #000000;
    border-right : 3px solid #ffffff;
    color : #ffffff;
    display : table;
    float : right;
    font-size : 28px;
    font-weight : 100;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 3px;
    padding : 6px;
}
.navigation ul li h1:hover {
    border-right : 3px solid #f43058;
    color : #f43058;
}
/* Positioning */
.navigation {
    font-family : 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin : 12px;
    position : fixed;
    right : 0;
    top : 0;
}
.navigation ul {
    font-size : 20px;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    text-align : right;
}
.navigation ul li {
    clear : right;
    color : #ffffff;
    float : right;
    list-style-type : none;
}
/* Second Level */
.navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display : block;
}
.navigation ul li ul li {
    background : #000000;
    border-right : 3px solid #ffffff;
    color : #ffffff;
    display : table;
    font-size : 18px;
    margin-bottom : 3px;
    padding : 6px;
}
.navigation ul li ul li:hover {
    border-right : 3px solid #f43058;
    color : #f43058;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var subMenu = jQuery("ul li ul li");
    var linkClick = jQuery("ul li").filter(":has(ul)");

    subMenu.hide();

    linkClick.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        subMenu.fadeToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing

`subMenu.fadeToggle("fast");`

in

`$(this).find('ul li').fadeToggle("fast");`

Because you want the child of the clicked element. Not every element.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx4CK/7/

Comment: You are welcome, plz accept this as answer if your bug is fixed so that not more StackOverflow members try to help you.

Comment: Done, I was waiting for the time limit to wear off so it let me.